# Compare all files in a folder

Tags: linux, bash, parsing, diff, asterisk

I've got script in crontab which creates every 30 minutes files with list of Offline peers in asterisk:

```
now=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M")
/usr/sbin/asterisk -rx 'sip show peers' | grep "Unspec" | sed 's/[/].*//' >> /var/log/asterisk/offline/offline_$now
```

I need to parse theese files and find extensions that were always offline, i.e. stings in files that were constant.

How can I do this?

Output is:

```
/usr/sbin/asterisk -rx 'sip show peers' | grep "Unspec" | sed 's/[/].*//' | tail -3
891
894
899

ls /var/log/asterisk/offline/
offline_201309051400  offline_201309051418  offline_201309051530  offline_201309051700 
offline_201309051830  offline_201309052000  offline_201309052130
offline_201309051405  offline_201309051430  offline_201309051600  offline_201309051730  
offline_201309051900  offline_201309052030  offline_201309052200
offline_201309051406  offline_201309051500  offline_201309051630  offline_201309051800    
offline_201309051930  offline_201309052100  offline_201309052230
```

Comment: Please provide some input and desired output, otherwise it is difficult to understand what it is required.

Comment: Constant over what period of time?

Comment: /usr/sbin/asterisk -rx 'sip show peers' | grep "Unspec" | sed 's/[/].*//' | tail -3

891
894
899

Comment: constant over all files

Answer (score 0):

This awk script will print the lines that are present in all of the files:

```
awk 'FNR==1{f++}{a[$0]++}END{for (i in a) if (a[i]==f) print i}' offline_*
```

How it works:

- With `FNR==1{f++}` we count the number of files that are parsed (FNR is equal to one for the first line of each file)
- with `{a[$0]++}` we count how many times each line has appeared.
- the `END` block prints the elements of the array that have been found f times.